# What should I do? I keep getting a <<Class 'KeyError'>> message

Tags: firefox

I keep getting a <<Class 'KeyError' on my upper right corner. First, it said something related to a Firefox update. I updated it, however I kept getting the message. Then, I uninstalled Firefox and now I keep getting the error but now it says:
<<<<class 'KeyError'>> ("The cache has no package named 'ubuntu-pro-client-(10n:amd64'")>>
I have no idea what to do. Help would be greatly appreciated.